# Spectroscopy: clarification about doppler shift

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spectroscopy, doppler-effect

I've just begun to study spectroscopy, and I need a clarification about the Doppler Effect.

Considering this graph:

[image]

could you explain me how I can see the doppler shift related to the deeper peak and how I can calculate it?

I'm confused because I haven't a course of Spectroscopy and this aspect was treated very very quickly in another course... is the doppler shift the inverse of the FWHM of the peak?

Comment: What are those two signals?

Comment: @YungHummmma in downward there is a triangular wave and the upper signal is what you see if a Rubidium cell is enlightened by a laser. (I have updated the question)

Comment: @sunrise: You didn't answer YungHumma's question.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Mmmh.. really? Consider a cell containing Rubidium and enlight it with a laser. Connect the system with an oscilloscope and give a triangular wave as input (so you can know when the Rubidium is resonant). This is the signal that you see downward. You can see the output in the upper signal. It is given by the difference between input signal and the signal received by the photodiode... But my question is about the interpretation of the doppler shift looking to the graph..

Comment: @sunrise: Yes, really. What is the detection scheme? What is the triangle wave being input into, is it being used as an amplitude modulator for the laser source? Is it being used as a frequency modulator in conjunction with an electro-optic modulator? Is the signal being detected via a lock-in amplifier? What wavelength range is the laser operating in? What spectral lines in rubidium do you think you are seeing? What do you mean by "when the rubidium is resonant"? What exactly is the setup? You can't just post a graph and expect people to know what it is without explaining what's going on.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I haven't a course of Spectroscopy and I know very few things of spectroscopy.. I can tell you that it was told me that the triangular wave was needed to identify the peaks of absorption and that $\lambda$=780 nm. When I said  "when the rubidium is resonant", I meant "when the rubidium absorbs makes the transition". I hope this can make clearer my question, I'm sorry..

Comment: Don't worry, it's fine, I'm just trying to get a picture of what the system looks like. There's a couple general things about Doppler that should be generally applicable. Doppler broadening is a major source of line-widening in high-temperature gaseous environments, and in the limit that Doppler broadening is the largest source of widening, the FWHM can be used to assess the temperature of the sample in a crude way. I'm assuming that when you say "Doppler shift", you're actually referring to "Doppler broadening"?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus oh yes! I'm sorry! There was an error of translation! I'm asking for "doppler broadening" and not "Doppler shift"! Excuse me!

Comment: So the Doppler broadening formula is given by $\Delta v=\left(\frac{8kT\ln 2}{m c^2}\right)^{1/2}f_0$, which tells you the FWHM of the line. You can find a derivation of this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_broadening, but the basic idea is that because the gas is hot, the atoms are flying around at high speeds, and so from the perspective of the atoms, the laser "looks" like it's a different color depending on whether they're moving towards or away from the beam (due to Doppler effect), so they absorb differently, widening the peak.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus so many thanks for your kindness! If I don't know the temperature and have to estimate $\Delta v$ looking to the graph (on x-axes we have time), can I find the FWHM of the peaks and and than calculate $\Delta v$ as $1/ \Delta t$?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus it is the only way that comes to my mind...

Comment: I kinda doubt $1/\Delta t$, since the FWHM is about 1 millisecond on your graph, which corresponds to $1/\Delta t$ of 1 KHz, whereas Rb doppler broadening at (for example) 500 K and 780 nm is 0.67 GHz, so it's off by nearly a million. Personally I'd try asking your teacher what exactly the graph axes, and in particular what the graph x-axis physically means; the reason I was asking for experimental details earlier was for this reason, to figure out what physical information the graph represents. Once you know what the x-axis means, the rest should be fairly easy to understand.